# using the contents of a combo-box in a sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables

I have a form with a combo box for manufacturers << you pick one which leads to>>
the second combo box (cbModel) for models you select one model then you go to the first text box (txtColour) enter the cars ccolour then to text box (txtRegNo) enter the registration. Press the add vehicle button and get this

```vb
Private Sub CreateVehicle()
    'Read in the model name and change it to a modelID no
    Dim ticket As String = cbModel.Text
    Dim queryString As String = "Select ModelID FROM Model WHERE Modelname = " & ticket & "' "

    ' Run Query
    SQL.RunQuery(queryString)


    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    'show what is in  dt is now
    MsgBox(dt)

    'temporary break to get first part working
    Exit Sub

    If Len(cbModel.Text) >= 0 And Len(txtColour.Text) >= 0 And Len(txtRegNo.Text) >= 0 Then

        'Add new user to database
        SQL.AddVehicle(cbModel.Text, txtColour.Text, txtRegNo.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please make sure you have filled in ALL Fields Correctly!")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

So I have fiddled aroundwith the Dim querysString line but I cannot get it to work, all I get is error messages "Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' '. and then InvalidOperation Exception was unhandled (this I think is due to the frst error stopping dt being filled ?)

Can anyone please help as I am going slowly crazy and the assignment is far from finished ! Thanks

Comment: There is a typo in your select statement, missing a quote

Comment: a) Use SQL parameters always b) that `SQL` thing looks like another SQL "helper" which may or may not be interfering; db Object have little reusability from query to query c) you should do data validation as a separate step and call `CreateVehicle` only if it passes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that ModelName is a field of some text type. If this is correct then, if you want to search a value in that field you need to put it between single quotes. For example

```
Dim queryString As String = "Select ModelID FROM Model " & _ 
                            "WHERE Modelname = 'ValueToSearch'"
```

In your code instead the quote is missing from the start of the value. So it is a simple typo that prevents your code to work.
But fixing it adding a quote is not the advice that I want to give you. Instead try to use a parameterized query

```
Dim queryString As String = "Select ModelID FROM Model " & _ 
                            "WHERE Modelname = @model"
' Run Query '
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(queryString, yourConnection)
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@model", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ticket 
Dim dt = New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
```

Now, it is difficult to say how to apply this method to your approach with

```
SQL.RunQuery(queryString)
```

but you should really change that code to accept parameterized queries because they are safer (no Sql Injection) and are not subject to simple parsing error like the one caused by the presence of a quote in your values.

Comment: Sorry @steve being new here you mention '@mode'l where did you get that ?    Dim ticket As String = cbModel.Text (This I believe created a variable ticket for the query) but you have put '@model' how does that come into existence ? As for the runquery it does the donkey work allowing you just to call it and select the querystring

Comment: in the query string the _@model_ text is just a placeholder. It simply sets the position where the effective value of the parameter should be applied when the query reaches the database engine by whatever code in sql server handles the query. In code has no meaning, it is just a string literal. Instead the Parameters.Add line associate the value of the _ticket_ variable to the parameter named _@model_ and all the stuff is passed to the database engine for processing

Comment: And about the RunQuery code, it is better to avoid these 'helper' as Plutonix said in its comment because rarely they help at all.